# WPF INotifyDataErrorInfo highlight ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a `ListBox` as such:

```
<ListBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkAdapters, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNetworkAdapter}" SelectionChanged="{s:Action SelectedNetworkAdapterChanged}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Ellipse Width="15" Height="15" Margin="5">
                    <Ellipse.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static wpf:NetworkAdapterStatus.Up}">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static wpf:NetworkAdapterStatus.Down}">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Ellipse.Style>
                </Ellipse>
                <StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Speed, StringFormat='Speed: {0}'}" FontSize="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" FontSize="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

`NetworkAdapters` is a collection of View Models that implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

With the current XAML, if there is an error in any of the View Models the whole `ListBox` will be highlighted red, but I would like just the single `ListBoxItems` that contains errors to be highlighted.

I had a look at similar questions such as:

[WPF ListBox ErrorTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250410/wpf-listbox-errortemplate) and 
[Validating a ListBoxItem rather than a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457318/validating-a-listboxitem-rather-than-a-listbox)

But I still can't make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

As per Krzysztof's advice, I tried wrapping the `StackPanel` around a border and using a `DataTrigger` as such:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasErrors}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Resources>
            <StackPanel> ... </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

However, what this produces is the following:

[image]

Which is slightly different from what I expected. I would like to have the highlight around the whole `ListBoxItem` not just part of it as per the image.

Comment: Change those TextBlocks to TextBox. Does it then work? If not then where are you setting HasError? Should be on the Networkadapter viewmodel that is presented to each row.

Comment: No, that doesn't work and I want the whole `StackPanel` that represents each `ListViewItem` to be highlighted, not the individual `TextBlocks`. The `HasError` is set on the `NetworkAdapter` ViewModel

Comment: I think you can work around that by setting HorizontalAligment to Strecht, and ContentAligment to Strech also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an `ItemContainerStyle` as below:

```
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Validation.HasErrors}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This will enable you to change the border of the `ListBoxItem` itself, so the whole things as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can forget about ErrorTemplate and just use DataTrigger to bind to `Validation.HasErrors`:

```
  <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type StackPanel}}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Validation.HasErrors}" Value="True"> <!-- change all text to red -->
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
</StackPanel>
```

If you want a highlight, you can wrap StackPanel with a Border and set its color to red in a style.

Comment: That *sort of* works, but still has a few issues. See my updated question.