# Validating a ListBoxItem rather than a ListBox INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, xaml, listboxitem, inotifydataerrorinfo

I tried Solutions Here :
[Validating a ListBoxItem rather than a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457318/validating-a-listboxitem-rather-than-a-listbox)
and
[WPF ListBox ErrorTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250410/wpf-listbox-errortemplate)
and
[WPF INotifyDataErrorInfo highlight ListBoxItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850251/wpf-inotifydataerrorinfo-highlight-listboxitem?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have a ListBox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ViewNewPanelsPairs}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LevelsTemplate}"  Style="{StaticResource PanelsListBox}"
                     SelectionMode="Single"  Margin="10" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentViewNewPanelsPair, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LevelItemTemplate}"/>
```

With the following item templates and itemcontainerstyle

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LevelsTemplate" DataType="{x:Type VM:ViewNewPanelsPair}">
    <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Content="{Binding View.Name}"   
              IsChecked="{Binding IsViewPanelsNotEmpty, Mode=OneWay}"
              IsHitTestVisible="False"
              IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}"/>
</DataTemplate>



<Style x:Key="LevelItemTemplate" TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Validation.HasErrors}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and following validations (implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo)

```
public ViewNewPanelsPair CurrentViewNewPanelsPair
    {
        get => currentViewNewPanelsPair;
        set
        {
            Set(() => CurrentViewNewPanelsPair, ref currentViewNewPanelsPair, value);
            ValidateProperty(nameof(CurrentViewNewPanelsPair));
        }
    }
```

and

```
protected void ValidateProperty(string PropertyName)
    {
        ClearErrors(PropertyName);
        switch (PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(ViewNewPanelsPairs):
                if (!ViewNewPanelsPairs.Any(x => x.IsViewPanelsNotEmpty))
                {
                    AddError(PropertyName, "At least one view must have new panels");
                }
                break;
            case nameof(CurrentViewNewPanelsPair):
                if (CurrentViewNewPanelsPair.NewPanels.Count != 0 && CurrentViewNewPanelsPair.NewPanels.Count!=ViewNewPanelsPair.OldPanels.Count)
                {
                    AddError(PropertyName, "New Panels must be equal to Old Panels");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

No matter how hard i try i always get the whole listbox highlighted surrounded with red border on error (not the listboxitem that has the error)
Is there something wrong with my code ??

Note : i debugged the code to make sure that there is actually error and there was and it shows it as a border around the whole listbox

Comment: The inotifydataerrorinfo implementation should be in the row viewmodel. Is yours in it's parent?

Comment: @Andy If iam getting what u said right, the implementation of inotifydataerrorinfo is in a base class that the viewmodel inherits from it , however i tried moving implementation to viewmodel class itself once and didn't work also

Comment: You're binding itemssource to a collection of things. What i mean by row viewmodel is the class that is one of those things. NOT the viewmodel exposes that collection of things.

Comment: @Andy, i got you now , no i did only implement the interface in the viewmodel , those things are the model and i didn't implement the interface in it , i will give it a try

Comment: @Andy i tried it but the whole error validation broke out and didn't work , i guess i have to stick with the implementation in view model

Comment: If you want errors to be reported at row level then you need to implement the interface and raise the events from the row viewmodel.  OR. Invent some completely different approach that doesn't use validation errors - which tells the parent viewmodel a row is invalid, sets a property on that row viewmodel and then you use a datatrigger to show it's invalid. This is possible but it's non standard approach and should be more work.

Comment: @Andy I just want errors at viewmodel level not row viewmodel and it shows the error correctly with the error string as a tip, my only problem is that it shows the red error box around the whole listbox not around the faulted selected item

Comment: Please read my comments again. To get a red error box around a row you need to EITHER raise the error from the row viewmodel. Not from it's parent. OR a completely different mechanism as I described. OR magic.

Comment: @Andy it worked and i posted the solution, thanks again for help and giving me the idea

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i implemented INotifyDataErrorinfo on my model class "ViewNewPaanelsPair" and bound the datatrigger of itemscontrolcontainer to the property that raises the error like this

`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NewPanels}" >
 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
 </DataTrigger>`

Thanks @Andy for your help